# Install node version 16 on M1 Apple mac

Tags: node.js, homebrew, apple-m1, rosetta

For new Apple M1 silicon mac-books, how can we install node on processor **x86_64 arch**.

According to node.js download page, they don't provide the mac installer for x86_64 processors. Please refer the download page - https://nodejs.org/en/download.

**Note:** Node Mac Installer only support ARM64 processor.

I have tried Rosetta terminal options, but not able to install node@16 with x86_64 arch on M1 mac machine. Please provide any suggestions to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do [`brew install node@16`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/node@16), but it requires some `PATH` environment variable hacks.

I'd recommend `nvm` or `asdf` plus `nodejs` plugin

Answer (score 0):

use `nvm` to install different node versions

1- `nvm install 16`
2- `nvm install 18`
3- `nvm use 16` to use node 16 in this terminal